# Monitor twitter hashtags in realtime with common search api?

Tags: api, search, twitter, streaming, hashtag

I've been working with the twitter search api, retrieving tweets with a php script run by a cron job, 3 or 4 times per hour.
All works fine, I can save some fields from the resulting tweets into mySQL for doing some research, contests, and accounting.

I begun experiencing some "trouble" some days ago when some hashtag hit Global Trending Topic, and the saved tweets werent't reflecting the real quantity of tweets We could see through search, etc.

So:

1- Should I use instead the twitter Streaming API?
2- Should I contact api AT twitter.com and request special permissions for my app or username?
3- Finally, is there a working way to acchieve this "realtime" monitoring script that can give more accurate and real results?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got a reply from twitter api staff...
It seems I should use STREAMING API, and they point me to this url

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#track

Hope it is useful for others

[image]

Comment: Hi, I know this is 5 years ago, but do you remember if this streaming API only returns feed from the authenticated user? for example, if I want to track #kardashians, do I get twitter search result of #kardashians, or only the current user's feed containing #kardashians?

Comment: @Rei as far I can remember, the streaming API is global, covers every tweet with the keyword you're looking for, but now this is provided only by twitter partners and it is expensive. I remember gnip but maybe there is another partner/provider. https://www.gnip.com/realtime/